# Is this the right way to specify a polygon location with JSON (and geoJSON)?

Tags: json, geojson

I have some JSON data that conveys some information about something. The information also includes location (for example location of a business). Now within the JSON file, can I specify the location as a polygon in the following manner? Am I doing anything wrong here (specially notice the "location"):

```
  .....
    "location":
    {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
    }

.....
```

Comment: Well, it's valid JSON; based on your tags, did you want it to be valid GeoJSON? If so, you should probably mention that in your question.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I meant geoJSON within a JSON object. edited question title